Bridge circular edge loops and getting them the same size
I was wondering how you could use bridge edge loops and simultaneously getting the bridged edges straight, considering that both edge loops connecting aren't exactly the same size. Is there a way to fix this afterhand?
This is what it looks like now:

So how do I get these two edge loops the same size? In a way that the smaller edge loop adjusts to the larger one.

Using S+X/Y/Z+0 adjusts the edge to the smaller edge loop, making the larger edge loop smaller. Can you adjust it in some way that it goes the other way around?

Picture of the topology:

Picture of the final result:

Thank you, and wish you all the best!

did you try S+X/Y/Z+0 to manually repair it? You only have a low poly mesh so it should be easy to do it manually, if you need advanced solution then I want to see it as well

Hi MikoCG and thank you for your answer. I tried your solution a couple of ways, but it doesn't really work the way I would like it to. I added a picture of the issue in the post.

Assuming your Bevels are set by a Bevel modifier, not hard-wired, this is a Snap. In this example, Snap is set to 'To: Vertex', and 'With: Active', and to influence 'Scale'.
The Transform Orientation is set to 'Normal', so it will work if the scaled element is not axis-aligned, and the Pivot is set to 'Median'
For the snap to operate in the right dimension, the scale transform should be made under a suitable constraint. Here, with the orientation set to Normal, that's SShiftZ (in the  selection Normal's XY)
Start the scale with a drag, and hit B to select a snap source. Then drag over the snap target:

If your bevels have been destructively put in by hand, you may want to delete those, at this stage of modelling.

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question Robin! :) Apologies for a late answer..
